# How can I set the url for an emberjs object reload to a custom url?

Tags: ember.js, reload

I'd like to customize the entire url, so I can use a regular querystring format, both for reloading an object and searching for specific objects.

Is this possible?

Comment: are you using ember-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but with some extra work.

Assuming you are using `ember-data` and the `RESTAdapter` you could override the [`buildURL`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L365) method, something like this:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function(record, suffix) {
    var customURL = '';

    // here you now have access to
    // this.namespace -> Namespace URL
    // record.toString() -> Record URL
    // suffix.toString() -> URL suffix

    // Now build your custom URL
    // ...

    // and return it
    return customURL;
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.